# Loading a plugin-enhanced library with Python

Tags: python, c, plugins, dynamic-linking

I am trying to interface a shared library using the `ctypes` mechanism in Python. This works well with normal libraries but now I have to deal with a library which extents its own functionality with a set of plugins. When I load this library using

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./liblibrary.so')
```

it first initializes all plugins found. And in this situation the plugins try to access symbols in `liblibrary.so` which are not found. If I use it from a C program and link `liblibrary` as a normal shared object everything works like a charm. `liblibrary.so` is linked with the `--export-dynmaic` flag enabled.

Here is the minimal working example:
liblibrary.c:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef int (*func_t)(int);

static int verbosity = 0;
static func_t worker;

    __attribute__((constructor))
void lib_init()
{
    void * handle;

    dlerror();
    handle = dlopen("./plugin.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error open: %s\n", dlerror());
        abort();
    }

    dlerror();
    worker = (func_t) dlsym(handle, "worker_function");
    if (!worker) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error dlsym: %s\n", dlerror());
        abort();
    }

}


int lib_getverbosity()
{
    return verbosity;
}

void lib_setverbosity( int _v )
{
    verbosity = _v;
}


int lib_work(int v)
{
    return worker(v);
}
```

Here is the example plugin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int lib_getverbosity();
extern int lib_setverbosity(int v);

int worker_function(int v)
{
    int verb = lib_getverbosity();
    printf("verbosity (plugin) : %d \n", v);
    return v * v;
}
```

and the Makefile:

```
all: liblibrary.so plugin.so


liblibrary.so: liblibrary.c
    gcc -shared -O2 -fPIC -g -rdynamic -Wl,--export-dynamic liblibrary.c -o liblibrary.so

plugin.so:
    gcc -shared -O2 -fPIC -g -rdynamic -Wl,--export-dynamic plugin.c -o plugin.so

clean:
    rm *.so

.PHONY: clean
```

When I run the about Python code now I obtain:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./liblibrary.so')
error open: ./plugin.so: undefined symbol: lib_getverbosity
```

**Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?**

Removing the auto-initialization or turning it into a function which must be called by the user first is not an option since in my application it will break a very old API/ABI.

Looking deeper in `liblibrary.so` with readelf shows:

```
readelf --dyn-syms library.so 

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 15 entries:
   Num:    Wert           Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlopen
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND abort@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTab
     4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     5: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlerror
     6: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dlsym
     7: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __fprintf_chk@GLIBC_2.3.4 (3)
     8: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     9: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
    10: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND stderr@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
    11: 0000000000001230    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 lib_setverbosity
    12: 00000000000010e0   128 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 lib_init
    13: 0000000000001240    10 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 lib_work
    14: 0000000000001220    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 lib_getverbosity
```

Which looks ok.

Comment: You should find a way to pass option `RTLD_GLOBAL` to `˙loadLibrary`.

Comment: This does not help. When I replace the load line with `CDLL('./library.so', mode=RTLD_GLOBAL)` I stil get `error open: ./plugin.so: undefined symbol: lib_getverbosity`.

Comment: Relink your `plugin.so` so that it explicitly depend on `liblibrary.so` (use `readelf -d plugin.so` to verify).